# Stuck at a sum of a binomial distribution

Tags: probability

So I'm having trouble in an assignment with probability. The assignment states the following:

In a box we have $n$ marbles ($n>9$) by which only one is black. In the box we pick out marbles one by one $2n$ times and return them the second we pick the up. Let $Z$ be the random variable that defines the amount of times the black marble has been picked up from those $2n$ pick outs.

-How many times can we expect to pick up the black marble.

-Find the value of the variable ***$k$*** so that the probability that a black marble will be picked out ***less than $k$ times*** is ***approximately*** $0.95$.

So using my solutions if ***p*** presents the probability that we will pick out a black marble then ***p = $\frac{1}{n}$*** so the random variable ***Z*** has a ***binomial distribution*** of ***$Z \sim B(2n, \frac{1}{n})$*** the we can calculate the expected value which is ***2***.

However for the second one I don't have an answer. Judging by the given statement then:

***$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} {2n\choose i}(\frac{1}{n})^{i} (\frac{n-1}{n})^{2n-i} = 0.95$***

and I don't know where to go from there.

Is this the correct formula I should be using or should I try a different formula like the normal approximation?

Comment: In what context is the problem given as? Have you learned both the poisson and normal approximation or just the normal approximation?

Comment: Just the normal approximation.

Comment: The sum you have doesn't have a nice closed form and so if your class/subject is focusing on the normal approximation, I would use that. Do you know how to solve for $k$ via the 95% quantile?